# curve fitting - linear regression

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

I have the following values for Xs and the corresponding value of Y

```
X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6      Y

13  14  15  16  16  N/A     25587

13  14  20  22  22  25      19672

16  17  18  23  27  30      9652

23  23  25  26  28  N/A     3603
```

To find the formula that express the relationship, I have used multiple linear regression
(by using `X1`, `X2`, `X3`, `X4`, and `X5`), but unfortunately the error was too big.

Is there another statistical method that I can use to formulate the relationship (which might be not-linear)?

Comment: A third degree polynomial can go through any given four points. [What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I need to find such a formula for Y as a function of X1,X2,X3,X4,X5       ,,,,, Y(X1,X2,X3,X4,X5) = .....

Comment: More cases are needed to try other methods